# htaccess removes the GET variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am editing a script and need to read GET variables to make my job done. But it seems the .htaccess file is manipulating it and removes everything at the end of custom URLs. I have no idea how to modify apache configurations to make it to works fine for the script yet me.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?route=$1/$2 [L] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?route=$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Here is a sample of URL I need to call:

```
http://domain.tld/controller/plugin/function/route?k1=v1&k2=v2
```

and the $_GET only contains one 'route' key with the value below:

```
controller/plugin/function/route
```

And other query strings are missed. What should I do for having them?

Comment: why the two separate blocks of rewrites? You can have multiple rules, especially if you use `[L]` to abort processing of further rules. just put the "most specific" ones first.

Comment: @MarcB it's the default htaccess file of the script. I haven't wrote it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the [QSA: Query String Append](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA) rewrite flag which does what it says on the tin.

For example:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?route=$1/$2 [L,QSA]`